# Gradle multi-module project Source Sets is missing in a module on Intellij Idea

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies, source-sets

I have imported a multi module gradle project to intellij idea, where one module has dependency on other. Based on that I can able to use classes from any module as it got the dependency.

But problem I am facing is, one of the modules is not resolving and I am not able to use any classes/objects of that module in any other module. Imports are showing in red color and giving compilation issue.

Strange thing is when I try to build the same code in command prompt, it compiles without issues. So I am suspecting Intellij Idea got the issue.

When I see the structure I can see `source sets` present for all modules except this module, that may be reason , it is not available. Attached the screenshot for the same.

Here ccf-core.monitoring is the module not able to find by other modules.

[image]

Also I can see the dependencies has been added for all the modules like below.

```
compile project(':ccf-core.monitoring')
```

I have tried creating new module and the module will become directory soon after gradle refresh.

Any leads will be helpful.